# Draw.io - how to export all tabs to images using command line

Tags: draw.io

I have installed on my PC draw.io app. I want to export all tabs with drawings to seperate files. The only options I have found is:

`"c:\Program Files\draw.io\draw.io.exe" --crop -x -f jpg c:\Users\user-name\Documents\_xxx_\my-file.drawio`

Help for draw.io

```
Usage: draw.io [options] [input file/folder]

Options:
(...)
  -x, --export                       export the input file/folder based on the
                                     given options
  -r, --recursive                    for a folder input, recursively convert
                                     all files in sub-folders also
  -o, --output <output file/folder>  specify the output file/folder. If
                                     omitted, the input file name is used for
                                     output with the specified format as
                                     extension
  -f, --format <format>              if output file name extension is
                                     specified, this option is ignored (file
                                     type is determined from output extension,
                                     possible export formats are pdf, png, jpg,
                                     svg, vsdx, and xml) (default: "pdf")
                                     (default: 0)
  -a, --all-pages                    export all pages (for PDF format only)
  -p, --page-index <pageIndex>       selects a specific page, if not specified
                                     and the format is an image, the first page
                                     is selected
  -g, --page-range <from>..<to>      selects a page range (for PDF format only)
(...)
```

is not supporting. I can use one of this:

```
  -p, --page-index <pageIndex>       selects a specific page, if not specified
                                     and the format is an image, the first page
                                     is selected
  -g, --page-range <from>..<to>      selects a page range (for PDF format only)
```

but how to get page-range or number of pages to select index?

Answer (score 15):

There is no easy way to find the number of pages out of the box with Draw.io's CLI options.

One solution would be export the diagram as XML.

```sh
draw.io --export --format xml --uncompressed test-me.drawio
```

And then count how many `diagram` elements there are. It should equal the number of pages (I briefly tested this but I'm not 100% sure if `diagram` element only appears once per page).

```sh
grep -o "<diagram" "test-me.xml" | wc -l
```

Here is an example of putting it all together in a bash script (I tried this on MacOS 10.15)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
file=test-me # File name excluding extension

# Export diagram to plain XML
draw.io --export --format xml --uncompressed "$file.drawio"

# Count how many pages based on <diagram element
count=$(grep -o "<diagram" "$file.xml" | wc -l)

# Export each page as an PNG
# Page index is zero based
for ((i = 0 ; i <= $count-1; i++)); do
  draw.io --export --page-index $i --output "$file-$i.png" "$file.drawio"
done
```

Comment: I love when apps supports CLI.

Comment: Nice. I have applied this grep-based solution in a bash-script that [diffs drawio diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78066100/1555615):

Answer (score 3):

OP did ask the question with reference to the Windows version, so here's a PowerShell solution inspired by [eddiegroves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5769/eddiegroves)

```
$DIR_DRAWIO = "."

$DrawIoFiles = Get-ChildItem $DIR_DRAWIO *.drawio -File

foreach ($file in $DrawIoFiles) {
    
    "File: '$($file.FullName)'"
    
    $xml_file = "$($file.DirectoryName)/$($file.BaseName).xml"

    if ((Test-Path $xml_file)) {
        
        Remove-Item -Path $xml_file -Force
    }
    
    # export to XML
    & "C:/Program Files/draw.io/draw.io.exe" '--export' '--format' 'xml' $file.FullName

    # wait for XML file creation
    while ($true) {
        if (-not (Test-Path $xml_file)) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
    # load to XML Document (cast text array to object)
    $drawio_xml = [xml](Get-Content $xml_file)

    # for each page export png
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $drawio_xml.mxfile.pages; $i++) {
        
        $file_out = "$($file.DirectoryName)/$($file.BaseName)$($i + 1).png"

        & "C:/Program Files/draw.io/draw.io.exe" '--export' '--border' '10' '--page-index' $i '--output' $file_out $file.FullName
    }

    # wait for last file PNG image file
    while ($true) {
        if (-not (Test-Path "$($file.DirectoryName)/$($file.BaseName)$($drawio_xml.mxfile.pages).png")) {
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
        }
        else {
            break
        }
    }
    # remove/delete XML file
    if ((Test-Path $xml_file)) {
        
        Remove-Item -Path $xml_file -Force
    }

    # export 'vsdx' & 'pdf'
    & "C:/Program Files/draw.io/draw.io.exe" '--export' '--format' 'vsdx' $file.FullName
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    & "C:/Program Files/draw.io/draw.io.exe" '--export' '--format' 'pdf' $file.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @eddie-groves, here's script that will export all diagrams from draw.io file using *sanitized* diagram names. You can probably turn it into script that will accept all `diagram_file_name`, `diagram_file_path`, `png_target_path` as parameters.

Tested on Debian 11, draw.io 20.8

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Export all drawio diagrams into PNG files. PNG files will have "sanitized" diagram names

export diagram_file_name=your_diagram_file_name # No extension
export diagram_file_path=./diagrams
export png_target_path=./diagrams/png

# Get diagram info. No need for --uncompressed : care only about <diagram name="..." ...> part.
drawio --export --format xml --output $diagram_file_path/$diagram_file_name.xml --page-index 0 $diagram_file_path/$diagram_file_name.drawio

# grep -Eo "name=\"[^\"]*": get name="... tokens/matches from xml
# cut -c7-: get diagram name (everything but starting 'name="'')
# sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/_/: replace all possible unsafe charactecter for file names with underscore (_) 
# tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]': make all lower case
# awk '{print NR,$1}': add sequence number (NR) to output to indicate index of diagram
# xargs -n2 sh -c: get 2 arguments (index and sanitized driagram name) and pass to shell command
# drawio --export...: export diagram at specified index (0-based) to PNG
cat $diagram_file_path/$diagram_file_name.xml \
    | grep -Eo "name=\"[^\"]*" \
    | cut -c7- \
    | sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/_/g' \
    | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' \
    | awk '{print NR,$1}' \
    | xargs -n2 sh -c \
    'drawio --export --format png --output $png_target_path/$1.png --page-index $(expr $0 - 1) $diagram_file_path/$diagram_file_name.drawio'


rm $diagram_file_path/$diagram_file_name.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers from @Eddie Groves and @arekam are very good.

I used them as a start point for the following script:

```bash
alias draw="/Applications/draw.io.app/Contents/MacOS/draw.io"

# Export all pages of a diagram to PNG
# Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65404843/2530295
draw-export-all-pages-to-png () {
    if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo 2>&1 "No input file entered"
        return 1
    fi
    if [[ ! "$1" == *.drawio ]]; then
        echo 2>&1 "Input file is not a .drawio file"
        return 1
    fi

    input="$1"
    output_dir="$(dirname "$1")/output"

    # Get the sanitized name of each page
    # Export the diagram to XML and parse the <diagram name="PAGE_NAME" .*> elements.
    tmp_xml=$(mktemp)
    draw --export --format xml --uncompressed "$input" --output "$tmp_xml" >/dev/null
    page_names=$(cat "$tmp_xml" | grep -E '<diagram( .*)?>' | grep -Eo 'name=\"[^\"]*' | cut -c7- | \
        tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | sed -e 's/[^a-z0-9_-]/_/g')

    # Export each page
    input_base_no_ext=$(basename "$input" .drawio)
    # Using `IFS=$'\n'` to convert a multiline string into an array.
    # See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92190
    (){ local IFS=$'\n'; page_array=($=page_names); }
    mkdir -p "$output_dir"
    for i in {1..${#page_array[@]}}; do
        draw --export --format png --output "$output_dir/$input_base_no_ext-${page_array[$i]}.png" \
            --page-index $(( $i - 1 )) "$input"
    done
}
```

**Notes:**

- It's a oh-my-zsh plugin, so code assumes MacOS and ZSH - not sure if will work in Bash without any modification.
- Code exports the pages to an `output` directory. You may want to improve the code and make the output dir an optional parameter to the function.

I shared the code as a Github Gist as well: https://gist.github.com/rarylson/8160ddf9a2b6cc5343fab8261a063aaa.

Answer (score 0):

Using drawio.exe you are able to drag and drop files onto this command script
[image]

Edit for your preferred naming, numbering, format, etc. but note pages in drawio just like PDF start internally as number 0. in my case pages= was at position 19 but if yours are different you may need to add extra tests.

pages2images.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=19* delims= " %%f in ("%~n1.drawio") do set drawio_%%f
set "trim=%drawio_pages:~1% nul
set /a "count=%trim% - 1" 2>nul
if %count% neq -2 (
  echo Pages start from 0 and end at %count%
  for /l %%p in (0,1,%count%) do echo starting page %%p&&draw.io --crop -p %%p -o "%~dpn1-page-%%p.png" -x -f png "%~1" && echo\
) else (
echo exporting page 0 && draw.io --crop -p 0 -o "%~dpn1-page-0.png" -x -f png "%~1" && echo\
)

pause
```

Intentionally it shows progress and a pause to show any errors as with this file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Its worth noting that if you want to run `draw.io` from the command line, the scripts here all assume you have installed you one of the common releases.

These are available here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases

If you install `draw.io` through some other **package** command or as a **Chrome Extension**, it may not be as easy to script due to install location and permissions.